# How to "jump" brackets in TeXstudio?

Tags: texmaker, editors, texstudio, keyboard

In Texmaker when you type the shortcut for `\frac`, you get something like `\frac{*}{*}`, but instead of asterisks, you have bullets. When you type something in the first pair of brackets, you can then hit tab to position the cursor between the second pair of brackets. How can I do this with TeXstudio?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

On a Windows PC and on Ubuntu, it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right arrow</kbd>

On Mac OS X it is <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Right arrow</kbd>

## <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇒</kbd>

It can be changed to <kbd>Tab</kbd> (<kbd>⇥</kbd>), but this is by default linked to another shortcut. If you go to the Preferences, "Shortcuts" tab, open up the "Editor" and the "Basic Key Mapping" list. Scroll down until you find

> Next placeholder or one word right

Double click on the shortcut and click for opening the drop down menu; there you can find Tab as in the following picture:

[image]

Answer "Yes" to both the following questions. Relaunch TeXStudio.

Comment: So how do I actually jump out of the placeholder? Everytime I type in a command (especially with empty arguments `\command{}`) the brackets just remain highlighted and prevent me from using Ctrl+Left/Right to move between words.

Comment: @Superbest: Even though it is a little late: You can get rid of the highlighting by pressing `enter`. This works either at the end of the highlighted string, or while it's completely marked.

Answer (score 3):

Just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>, that is, hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and press the “Right Arrow Key”.

Obviously, while the fields are highlighted you can move left using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>.

It works for me on my *TeXstudio 2.5.2 (SVN 3651)*

Comment: In my Windows installation of TeXstudio the default (I can’t remember to have changed that) is Ctrl+Left and Ctrl+Right. (See also [chat transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9296074#9296074).)

Comment: On may Mac it’s `[cmd]`+`[left]`/`[right]` and I guess that is the default …

Comment: @Tobi On my Mac (El Capitan, TeXstudio 2.11.2) `⌘` + `←`/`→` was mapped to "Move cursor to line start/end" by default. There was no mapping for "Next/Previous placeholder" by default.