# How do I complete placeholders is TeXstudio using keyboard

Tags: texstudio

I know how to [jump between placeholders in TeXstudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112745/how-to-jump-brackets-in-texstudio/112787), but not how to exit them. In Eclipse and other editors with similar functionality, I press enter and then the placeholder
disappears and the cursor is (usually) placed after the inserted text. It TexStudio when I press enter, the placeholders disappears but it also treats the enter as a character input, inserting a new line and overwriting any selected text. This is pretty useless, especially when filling out text between brackets where you as good as never want a newline.

How can I exit/finalize/complete placeholders in a template, without inserting extra text/newlines.

Thank you.

**EDIT** I am using both mac and windows on and off, so please share hotkeys for as many platforms you know :)

Answer (score 4):

There is currently no builtin functionality for this. As a workaround you can create a script (Menu `Macros -> Edit Macros...`)

```
%SCRIPT
var phID = editor.currentPlaceHolder();
if (phID >= 0) {
    editor.removePlaceHolder(phID);
} else {
    editor.insertText('\n');
}
```

Then go to Options -> Shortcuts and bind the Return key to that Skript (You need to actually type `return` in the dropdown box because it's not in the dropdown list).

Note: Most of the time, placeholders are used for parameters in brackets. There you can simply continue typing the corresponding closing bracket and the placeholder will vanish. But I think the return is a reasonable addition to the concept and we will natively support it in the next release of TXS.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem with this issue. But the greatest inconvenience is in using Ctrl + Left/Right in text editing. If you don't have a placeholder this shortcuts mean jump to previous/next word. And if there's a placeholder in a direction, it jumps to a placeholder.

Still I do not recommend to use `return` as a shortcut (see previous post), because this script will discard useful return features like: Make a choise from a list of possible autocompletions.

I recommend to use `Shift+Return` or `Ctrl+Return` (default for newline with \\) as a shortcut for this script.

Comment: The newest version of TeXstudio can do it from the box (`Ctrl+Enter`, while selecting a placeholder).